# How would I use HashTable or HashMap to count?

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

For example, given the data

```
Name: 1234, Qty: 100
Name: 1234, Qty: 100
Name: 1234, Qty: 100
Name: 1234, Qty: 200
Name: 1234, Qty: 200
```

The expectation is:

```
Name: 1234, Qty: 700
```

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple values for same key in the first place?

Comment: @AndrewT. It is NOT possible. The map will be updated with the latest value.

Comment: @TonyD I acknowledge the error and apologize for that.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that you repeatedly find the name-specific cumulative sum in the hashtable, adding the next value to it.  In pseudo-code:

```
for name, qty in input
    hashtable[name] += qty
```

Depending on your language, you may have to explicitly check whether there's an existing hashtable entry for "name" and create one with the initial "qty" value.

Comment: This is by far the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

In a HashMap, a key can only be associated with one value, so you will need to use a `HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>` or a [MultiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) to achieve this.